# Tabular import function missing on Graph DB desktop, any solutions?

Tags: database, graph, desktop, tabular, ontorefine

I have the desktop version of Graph DB and I wanted to use the function import -> tabular. However, I do not have this function? I tried installing the Graph DB free but it is still not there. What can I do?

Hope Grijseels

I reinstalled the program, tried another version

Answer (score 3):

With the recent major release of GraphDB 10, Ontotext Refine (formerly OntoRefine) has emancipated itself and has become its own independent product. All existing functionalities are still available.

It can be downloaded for free as a platform independent distribution package (.zip), as a Docker image or as a native app for one of the operating systems - https://www.ontotext.com/products/ontotext-refine/